# Redirect page displays blank when using $_POST

Tags: php

After some trial and error, I managed to identify the PHP code that creates the problems:

```
  <?php
  if isset($_POST['hoponhopoff']){
  $adults = intval($_POST['bilet_intreg']);
  $price_adults = $adults * 10;
  $children= intval($_POST['bilet_redus']);
  $price_children = $children * 4;
  $free= intval($_POST['bilet_gratis']);
  // Added on 27.07.2015
  $fname= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fname']);
  $lname= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lname']);
  $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);
  $phone= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['phone']);
  $address= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address']);
  }
  ?>
```

I tried removing the conditional statement, tried with just one of the variables, tried without mysqli_real_escape_string... nothing seems to work. There's a bunch of HTML code after this portion of code and if I remove these lines it displays as it should. If I leave them untouched then the pages shows blank instead of showing its content. Any ideas why this would happen?

Note: Because of the typos in the first code I posted I updated the code. The results are the same, a blank page.

Comment: Check your `( )` your missing some and have some too much.

Comment: `&_POST` should be `$_POST` in your `mysqli_real_escape_string()` functions. Also, you're missing the `()` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you both for noticing those problems. Updated my question since that didn't solved the problem.

Comment: You haven't updated your `if` statement. It should be `if (isset($_POST['hoponhopoff'])) {`.

Comment: Thank you, haven't noticed that one. Please post it as a solution to my question so I can accept it and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code.

First, your `if` statement must include `()` like so: `if($bool)`. Therefore, your first line must be:

```
if (isset($_POST['hoponhopoff'])) { // notice the () enclosing the condition
```

Secondly, you had your `$_POST[]` variables wrong in your `mysqli_real_escape_string()` functions. Variable are called with `$`, not `&`. Therefore, your code must be as such:

```
$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['fname']); // notice the $ instead of &
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lname']); // notice the $ instead of &
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']); // notice the $ instead of &
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['phone']); // notice the $ instead of &
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['address']); // notice the $ instead of &
```

Using `&` before `$var` (ie. `&$var`) makes a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) to this variable.